# Start local SMTP server

Tags: python, windows, smtp

I'm going to transfer crash dumps from clients to me through the mail mechanism. Therefore, I can't use any public SMTP servers, as packing any account's credentials with the application is unacceptable.

Therefore, I need to send mails through my application directly to the destination mail server.

How can I achieve this in python? (I'm using windows so `sendmail` is not an option)

Comment: Your description sounds like you want to know how to "send mails through my application directly to the destination mail server". But your title is "Start local SMTP server". Is this because you thought you needed to start a server to send mails (in which case: you don't), or because the title is what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) in the standard library.

Trying to write code that can send mail to anyone is problematic, because `smtplib` connects to servers client-to-server style rather than server-to-server-relay style.

But if you only need to send mail to one particular server, which you control, it's trivial. Just configure your server at 'mail.example.com' to accept any mail from 'crash-reports@example.com' to 'crash-reports@example.com'.

Your code will look something like this:

```
import smtplib
addr = 'crash-reports@example.com'
def send_crash_report(crash_report):
    msg = ('From: {}\r\nTo: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
           addr, addr, crash_report)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.example.com')
    server.sendmail(addr, [addr], msg)
    server.quit()
```

As a side note, if you're just starting on a crash report collector, you may want to consider using a web service instead of a mail address. You're going to run into problems with people who can't access port 25 through their corporate firewall/proxy, write code that extracts the crash reports from an inbox (and/or searches via IMAP or mbox or whatever), deal with spammers who somehow find `crash-reports@example.com` and flood it with 900 messages about Cialis for each actual crash report, etc.

Comment: @abarnet I am trying to send a mail using a python script through a local host. So i need to install an smtp server in my system for this task ? Also I am using osx 10.10 yosemite